# how to unparent objects without everything moving?

Tags: parent

So I got this model of a robot and I had to rotate the whole model (which is made up of several non-joined meshes) so I parented every single part to the body and now when I unparent everything goes haywire. Anyone got any ideas on how I can unparent them without everything moving?

This is how it looks parented [image]

And this is what happens when it gets unparented (I used alt+p clear parent)[image][image]

I got another question. I need to rig this model and keep everything unjoined (because I dont want anything to bend since this is a robot made up of solid parts) any tips on that?

Here is a download link if anyone wants to have a closer look: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50768

Comment: for your second question, you don't need to keep your objects unjoined, what you need is to parent your object to the armature "with empty groups", it will just create vertex groups with the bone names, but no vertices will be actually assigned to these groups, then you'll assign the vertices you want to the vertex group you want in the Vertex Groups list.

Comment: Thank you again, I really love how active the blender community is and how everyone is willing to help. People like you are the heroes we need

Comment: you're welcome  ;)  do you need a more precise answer for the "with empty groups" option or is it clear enough for you?

Comment: If you want to rig different rigid objects, I suggest to use the Ctrl P "bone" option: in this way Blender has to calculate less and the animation process will be smoother in the viewport.

Comment: yes ctrl P > "bone" is a possibility, the problem is that if you then choose to join your different object into one, you'll have to redo it all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> (*Clear Parent*) > *Clear and Keep Transformation*. Otherwise the child will come back to the position it got before the parentage.

Comment: I should've guessed that... Every time I ask questions about blender and get such an answer I feel so dumb.

Thank you very much - worked perfectly

Comment: Idk how to pm other users, so I figured this will work. I fixed the video on my animation post if you want to help :)